# assign values to a variable name with mutate

Tags: r

I'd like to set the column name with a variable so that I can use this code in a function

This is my code

```
cols <-
  data.frame(
    vars = names(titanic),
    types = unlist(lapply(titanic, class)),
    row.names = NULL)
    
facs <-
  cols[cols$types == "factor", ]

i <- 1

    titanic %>% 
      select(facs$vars[i]) %>% 
      mutate(vars = fct_explicit_na(as.factor(get(facs$vars[i])), 
                                     na_level = "(Missing)")) %>% 
      select(get(facs$vars[i] = vars)
```

I'd like for the vars column to be renamed "gender" since that's the value in the facs df.

Comment: Take a look at the [`dplyr` docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html) and intro. It's very rare that you'll be referring to columns in this way. If you want to write a function with `dplyr`, you'll probably need to use tidyeval, which can be confusing, though it's gotten some improvements in the past couple years. I'd recommend getting the hang of `dplyr` verbs first; after that, I prefer [this post](https://colinfay.me/tidyeval-1/) on tidyeval to some of the official vignettes

Comment: The example from `??dplyr::across` will likely be helpful.  `iris %>%
as_tibble() %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character))`

Comment: I'd like to do this for the purpose of a function, thank you!